# Chmod not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: chmod, pycrypto

Trying to get pycrypto installed in Windows. At the command prompt, I type python setup.py build. Things start out ok, but when it gets to 'running build_configure', I get this error message and things come to a halt:

> chmod not recognized as internal or external command

I tried downloading and installing chmod, but that didn't change anything.

Anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: `chmod` is a Unix command.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: Yes, I know. But I'm working in Windows, and I know that pycrypto can be installed on windows, so there must be a solution. Maybe I need to be working in MinGW or Cygwin?

Comment: Have you seen [this article](http://www.razorvine.net/blog/user/irmen/article/2009-12-05/166)?  Also https://www.google.com/#q=Building+pcrypto+on+Windows

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was running this from a Windows cmd prompt. I ran it from MinGW and it got past this part.

Comment: Worked with gitbash as well .

Answer (score 11):

I found [this answer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/345794/chmod-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external.html) to solve the issue by installing "Git for Windows" and adding the "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" path to the system %PATH% environment variable.

It's work for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to install msys package under MinGW

[image]

and add following entries in your PATH env variable.

- `C:\MinGW\bin`
- `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` [This is where you will find chmod executable]

Then run your command from normal windows command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

like people said before, chmod is a UNIX command. it is also available in gitbash.
If you are using windows you need to understand that chmod 400 basically changes your permissions on the file.

and you can change the permissions on the UI like this:

1. select .pem file -> right click -> properties
2. Security > Advanced > Disable inheritance
3. Remove all Users
4. Add > Select a principal
5. In "Enter the object name to select" type your Windows username > ok
6. Give all permissions > ok > apply

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no chmod command in Windows.

Either use Explorer's properties page for the file, or from a command shell use the attrib or cacls commands.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Colab, which is cloud-based, and allows you to execute Unix-like commands, including 'chmod,' within code cells by prefixing them with '!' (ex: !chmod).

Colab provides a cloud-based Jupyter Notebook environment, enabling seamless integration of code, data, and collaboration, all in one place, without having to install the required resources.

Answer (score 0):

use this command for windows
"filename.pem" /inheritance:r /grant:r "$($env:USERNAME):R"