# EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

i am still new and i wanted to start learning react native but when i was looking up how to install it said npm i -g create-react-native-app and that didnt work so i tried npm i -g react native and it keeps saying the same err

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\expo-cli
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\expo-cli'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\expo-cli'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\expo-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

and i looked up how to solve it and all i found was to clear the cache and i did that and it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

It is not having write permission. Use the following command in your terminal of root folder

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

Comment: do i put something in front of it becaue when i do what exactly you put it says chmod is not a command

Comment: Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11380955)